# How to split a polynomial string and keeping the minus sign with the negative token?

Tags: java, string, split

How can I split a string looking like this `[-3*x^4+34*x+8-13*x^2+x^3]`by either [+] or [-] and keeping the minus sign with the minus token ?

Comment: Use a *polynomial parser*... Not regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj

I got this so far , 

`String testString = "-3*x^4+34*x+8-13*x^2+x^3";
    System.out.println
       (java.util.Arrays.toString(testString.split("(?<=[-+])")));`

Comment: what would be the expected output?

Comment: the previous code gives me [-, 3*x^4+, 34*x+, 8-, 13*x^2+, x^3] but I want something like this 
[-3*x^4,+34*x,+8,-13*x^2,+x^3] @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to use positive lookahead assertion.

```
String testString = "-3*x^4+34*x+8-13*x^2+x^3"; 
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(testString.split("(?=[+-])")));
```

Output:

```
[-3*x^4, +34*x, +8, -13*x^2, +x^3]
```